# Installation error for Oracle DBI module for perl?

Tags: macos, oracle, perl

I get the error oci.h missing on running the installation:
`cpan DBD::Oracle` on `OS X 10.8`. 
How can I fix this?

The specific error message is:

```
/usr/bin/perl -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/Oracle/g" /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-  2level/auto/DBI/Driver.xst > Oracle.xsi

/usr/bin/perl /System/Library/Perl/5.12/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /System/Library/Perl/5.12/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Oracle.xs > Oracle.xsc && mv Oracle.xsc Oracle.c
clang -c  -I/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -Os   -DVERSION=\"1.68\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.68\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"  -Wall -Wno-comment -DUTF8_SUPPORT -DORA_OCI_VERSION=\"11.2.0.3\" -DORA_OCI_102 -DORA_OCI_112 Oracle.c
In file included from Oracle.xs:1:

./Oracle.h:37:10: fatal error: 'oci.h' file not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I managed to solve it by adding the `include` directory of the oracle instance client sdk to `C_INCLUDE_PATH` env variable and installing it from the source directory:

```
tar xzf DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz
cd DBD-Oracle-1.74
export C_INCLUDE_PATH="/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2/sdk/include" 
perl Makefile.PL 
make 
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to install DBD::Oracle without having installed the appropriate Oracle client prerequisite. Consult [DBD::Oracle::Troubleshooting::Macos](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.68/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Macos.pod), [DBD::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/~pythian/DBD-Oracle-1.68/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm) installation nodes, ensure that the require environment variables are setup. It's easier to install this module outside of the cpan tool.